# scipy.optimize.minimize does not converge in multivariable optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize, convergence

I want to find the values of **board_trim** and **lm** that will give me the **lowest** (closest to 0) value for **Board_Moments**.

For this I use **scipy.optimize.minimize**, but it does not converge. I really can't figure it out.

**with** **Parameters**:

displacement = 70

b = 6.5

deadrise = 20

LCG = 10

Vs_ms = 23.15 #ms

rho = 1025

mu = 1.19e-6

```
def Board_Moments(params):

    board_trim, lm = params

    displacement_N = displacement * 9.81 #kN  

    lp = Lp(Vs_ms, b, lm)
    N = displacement_N * cos(d2r(board_trim))             #Drag Forces Perpendicular to the keel

    #Taking moments about transom at height of CG

    deltaM = (displacement_N * LCG) - (N * lp) #equilibrium condition
    return deltaM
```

where lp:

```
def Lp(Vs_ms, b, lm):

    cv = Cv(Vs_ms, b)
    Lambda = Lambda_(lm, b)
    Cp = 0.75 - (1 / (5.21 * (cv / Lambda)**2 + 2.39))
    lp = Cp * lm
    return lp
```

and

```
def Cv(Vs_ms, b):

    cv = Vs_ms / (9.81 * b)**0.5 
    return cv
```

and

```
def Lambda_(lm, b):

    lambda_ = lm / b
    return lambda_
```

the optimization is done with:

```
board_trim = 2 #initial estimate

lm = 17.754 #initial estimate

x0 = [board_trim, lm]

Deltam = minimize(Board_Moments, x0, method = 'Nelder-Mead')
print(Deltam)
```

The error I get:

```
   final_simplex: (array([[ 1.36119237e+01,  3.45635965e+23],
   [-1.36046725e+01,  3.08439110e+23],
   [ 2.07268577e+01,  2.59841956e+23]]), array([-7.64916992e+25, 
   -6.82618616e+25, -5.53373709e+25]))

       fun: -7.649169916342451e+25

   message: 'Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.'

      nfev: 401

       nit: 220

    status: 1

   success: False

         x: array([1.36119237e+01, 3.45635965e+23])
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Are `Vs_ms` and `b` parameters (to be optimised), or constants?

Comment: Include the result of the (failed) minimisation. That is, the OptimizeResult, with the values of all its attributes.

Comment: Vs_ms and b are constants

Comment: make **simple and reproducible** example and we might help better

Comment: Please add the error to your question (and format it); it's important to the question, and unreadable in a comment.

Comment: @9769953 , I updated the post with the code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mention

> that will give me the lowest (closest to 0) value for Board_Moments.

But minimize will search the absolute minimum. If you print the intermediate values for `deltaM` (which you should have done to debug your problem), you'll find they just get smaller and smaller, below zero (so -10, -100, -500 etc. That kind of progression).

To get as close to zero as possible, the solution is simply: return the *absolute* value of `deltaM` from `Board_Moments`:

```
def Board_Moments(params):
    # code as before ...
    deltaM = (displacement_N * LCG) - (N * lp) #equilibrium condition
    
    # This print function would have shown the problem immediately
    #print(deltaM)

    # Use absolute (the built-in `abs` or `np.abs`; 
    # doesn't really matter for a single value)
    # to get close to zero
    return np.abs(deltaM)
```

For this particular case and fix, the result I get is:

```
final_simplex: (array([[ 2.32386388, 15.3390523 ],
       [ 2.32394414, 15.33905343],
       [ 2.32390145, 15.33905283]]), array([5.33445927e-08, 7.27723091e-08, 1.09428584e-07]))
           fun: 5.334459274308756e-08
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 107
           nit: 59
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([ 2.32386388, 15.3390523 ])
```

(and if you comment out the print function, you'll see it easily converge towards zero.)